# JavaScript compare string using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string and willing to compare string,there are some example that i want to check,here is my string

A. Method Statement:

and I'm willing to allow following

(1) return true if starts with A,B,a,b etc both case sensitive are allow
(2) allow space between A. Method
(3) Must Contain `Method Statement` for both case sensitive are allow

e.g.

1. a. Method Statement:
2. A. method Statement:
3. A. Method statement:
4. A. Method STatement:

   etc

how can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried to do. Where is your attempts? Please show some effort.

Comment: `/[a-z]\.\smethod statement/i`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"A. Method Statement".match(/[a-z]\.\s?method statement/i)
```

Comment: I think OP means a,b etc as in a-z.

Answer (score 0):

Get a good reference such as [MDN's Regular Expression Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

The parts you need

**A character set.**

`[xyz]` or `[a-z]`

Matches any one of the enclosed characters. You can specify a range of characters by using a hyphen.

**A period**

`\.`

It has to be escaped with a `\` since `.` means any character.

**A space**

`\s`  or `" "` [without quotes]

Matches a single white space character, including space, tab, form feed, line feed and other unicode spaces. Equivalent to [ \t\r\n].

**Optional Match**

`?`

Matches the preceding item 0 or 1 time.

**Sting match**

Just type out the string you want matched

**Ignore case flag**

`i`

---

So put it together and what do you have

```
var myRegExp = /[a-z]\.\s?method statement/i;
```